# Xcode makefile or compilation options

Tags: xcode, gnu

I am new to Xcode. Once I configure my C++ command line application to build, and it builds successfully, I have sometimes no clue about how Xcode calls GNU C++.

Is it possible to get the makefile that Xcode creates or how to see the compilation options created by Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't actually create a makefile; among it's other functionality, Xcode replaces make.  But you can see all the options, etc., Xcode uses to build you code.  Just open the project in Xcode, and select Get Info from the File menu.  Browse the resulting dialog box for almost anything you could possibly want to know about Xcode build settings.

Or you could use a tool like[PBTOMAKE](http://members.bellatlantic.net/%7Evze35xda/software.html), an OS X application that can convert Xcode projects into makefiles, but it hasn't been updated in a few years.

Comment: Unfortunately, PBTOMAKE doesn't work. Seems like project file format has been changed since 2006 (date of doc-manual)